# Error from powershell start-process

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to launch a process from powershell like this:-

```
$proc = (start-process $myExe -argumentList '/myArg True' -windowStyle Minimized -passthru)
```

This mostly works, however intermittently I get this error:-

> This command cannot be executed completely because the system cannot find all the information required.

Googling for the error yields nothing and - to me at least - it's meaningless. The machine is quite tightly locked down and I suspect a configuration problem, but it would be easier to solve if I knew what the error was about.

The message appears to come from Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll

Does anyone know what it means or even what "information" it can't find?

Comment: Are you sure that message is not output by `$myExe`?

Comment: Yes, if you search that DLL it's in there as a string.

Comment: A quick look at the DLLs source using dotPeek, suggests that this error is raised, when the process could not be started for some reason. You're sure that there isn't more output available? Also try to execute the command in question directly from the command prompt and see if it dumps any errors.

Comment: First use `$Error.Clear()` to clear the error list. Then run your command. Look at the `$Error` list. On the appropriate one (most likely `$Error[0]`), look at the `$Error[0].Exception`, then `.Exception.InnerException` ad infinitum until something useful appears

Comment: Thanks guys I'll try this stuff out and get back to you...

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
Set-Variable -Name myExe c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
$proc = (start-process -FilePath $myExe -argumentList '/k' -windowStyle Minimized -passthru )
```

replace the cmd.exe with your exe